Why is getToken() not equal in main app and FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage in Flutter using Android 15?
I have an Flutter app that runs the MyApp() in runZonedGuarded() like this:
    void main() async {
          await runZonedGuarded(() async {
          WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
                FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandlerInMain);
        
          await Firebase.initializeApp();
    
          var token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance
                      .getToken(vapidKey: DefaultFirebaseConfig.vapidKey);
          debugPrint("FCM token: $token");
    
          runApp(MyApp());
    }, (error, stackTrace) {
    throw (error);
  });

And a simple background handler like this
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandlerInMain(RemoteMessage message) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    
    var token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getToken(vapidKey: DefaultFirebaseConfig.vapidKey);
    debugPrint("FCM token: $token");
}

In Android 15 I see that FCM token received in backgroundhandler are not the same as the token in main app.
On the second message received in _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandlerInMain() it will show the same token again. On Android 14 and earlier I see the same token on backgroundhandler and main app.
Anyone knows if Android 15 handles this different?
Enviroment
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.4, on macOS 15.0.1 24A348 darwin-arm64 (Rosetta), locale en-NO)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)

